# Publish unpacked zipped file to chrome extensions to bulk users without chrome webstore

Tags: google-chrome-extension

We require suggestions how can we automate for publishing unpacked zipped file to chrome extensions to bulk users without chrome webstore.

Hi Team
We require suggestions how can we automate for publishing unpacked zipped file to chrome extensions to bulk users without using chrome webstore.